# Poll Windows folder for new files in Matlab?

Tags: windows, matlab, polling

I need to write a MATLAB script that polls a folder in Windows 7 so that when a new image file is written to disk, it is displayed automatically in MATLAB. I need help writing the polling part.

Based on some Googling, right now I have:

```
dir_content = dir(fbdir);
filenames = {dir_content.name};
current_files = filenames;

while true;
  dir_content = dir(fbdir);
  filenames = {dir_content.name};
  new_files = setdiff(filenames,current_files);
  if ~isempty(new_files)
    DO MY THING HERE
  end;           
end
```

But the problem is that it doesn't catch all images, and sometimes an image may show up but not be fully written to disk, throwing an error in Matlab when I try to load it. Is there a better way to poll for new files (only ones that have been fully written to disk)?

Comment: Are you looking for a new image file or just any new file?

Comment: Specifically a new .PNG or .JPG file. I can also anticipate what the name of the new file will be, if that helps. But I need to load it immediately after it is written to disk (using a separate toolbox for Matlab, but I don't think that's relevant here).

Comment: Thanks, looks like using a timer object solved it.

Comment: And when you find a new file, you should put your `load()` in a retry loop with a `pause(0.2)` or so to work around that error you get when you try to load a partially-written file. The code in the linked example doesn't deal with that case .You could just wait until it stops growing in size, but that's just a heuristic and you'd have to try/catch your load anyway to really avoid errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
initial_count = numel(dir('*.jpg')) + numel(dir('*.png'));
while 1
    count = numel(dir('*.jpg')) + numel(dir('*.png'));
    if count>initial_count
        DO MY THING HERE %%// New image file found
        initial_count  = count;
    end
end
```